# merging two commits skips a file from the merged commit, using git checkout -- filename brings the changes

Tags: git

i have two commits A, B
i want to merge B into A

**git checkout A

git merge B**
this skips a file(does not merge it even though the file was changed)
if i discard the merge and
**checkout commit A (detached head)

git checkout B -- fileName.txt**
(this changes only the selected file to the B version)

then the changes are brought correctly.

to double check i used
**git diff  A B -- fileName.txt**

And it showed that there are indeed changes between the two commits regarding this file.
Is there a way to make sure that the merge didn't discard other files like it discarded this file ?

Comment: Could you create a simple reproducible example? What command were you using? It sounds like the file was not part of the commit in the first place, otherwise it should not be discarded or ignored by git.

Comment: I don't think the merge *did* "discard" changes. I think you misunderstand how `git merge` works. Find the *merge base* commit and run *two* `git diff` commands, from the merge base to the two commits in question, and you might find this enlightening.